# No intellisense on aspx.cs page?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

For some reason, VS2010 refuses to do automatic code completion on ASPX.CS files. Any other file works just fine, but not these. I can do CTRL+SPACE, that works, but it should be automatic.

Is there a setting to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked under Options --> Text Editor--> C# to see that the mappings are what you expect?

Comment: Odd,I started the solution now, and the problem did not occur. Could have been something temporary.